# detecting a newline in fgets

Tags: c, shell, prompt, fgets

I am attempting to create a C program to be used as a simple command line interpreter for a UNIX system. I use fgets() to read user input which then stores input in a buffer to be parsed. If the only user input is pushing enter, I would like to reissue the prompt. Is there a way to detect if the return key was the only key entered at the prompt? Below is a snippet of code I have tried so far:

```
for (;;) {
    printf("$prompt$ ");
    fflush(stdout);

    fgets(commandBuffer, 200, stdin);

    /* remove trailing newline:*/
    ln = strlen(commandLine) - 1;
    if(commandLine[ln] == '\n')
        commandLine[ln] = '\0';

    /* attempt to handle if user input is ONLY return key:*/
    if(commandLine[0] == '\n')
        continue;
```

Comment: For the (rare) case of `fgets()` returning a zero-length string the code will fail miserably.

Comment: That can be fixed by checking the sizeof.

Comment: @JFA Please expand on how "checking the sizeof" helps.

Comment: @chux I was responding to alk's statement, but now that I think about it, I think you want `strlen` instead. I was thinking of `sizeof` for something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace

```
 if(commandLine[0] == '\n')
```

with

```
if(commandLine[0] == '\0')
```

The code just above this replaces newlines with nuls.

Answer (score 1):

```
ln = strlen(commandLine);
while (ln > 0 && commandLine[ln-1] == '\n')
    --ln;
commandLine[ln] = '\0';
```

is a more compact solution handling special cases like empty input.

Answer (score 0):

A popular one-liner to remove a potential new line is

```
if (fgets(commandBuffer, 200, stdin)) {
  commandBuffer[strcspn(commandBuffer, "\n")] = '\0';
```

The below suffers a problem when `strlen(commandLine)` returns 0.  This happen when the input line read begins with a *null character*.

```
fgets(commandBuffer, 200, stdin);
ln = strlen(commandLine) - 1;  // ln could be outside 0...199  
if(commandLine[ln] == '\n')    // commandLine[ln] is then undefined behavior
```

Otherwise perform like [@ensc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20201031/2410359).

```
if (fgets(commandBuffer, 200, stdin)) {
  ln = strlen(commandLine);
  while (ln > 0 && commandLine[ln-1] == '\n') {
    --ln;
  }
  commandLine[ln] = '\0';
```